# .htaccess DirectoryIndex does not work

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have two index files in my public_html folder (Apache), index.html and index.php

By default Apache seems to be directing traffic to index.php, so I want to change that to index.html. I added a .htaccess file in the same directory with this in it:

> DirectoryIndex index.html

But when visitors go to the website (www.example.com/), they are still directed to index.php

Why is this?

Answer (score 13):

For those who are still searching for the answer - just like the OP suggests, add the following line to your .htaccess file:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

Make sure your hosting is allowing htaccess override in httpd.conf

```
AllowOverride All
```

If it's not enabled, you'll have to contact your hosting provider.

Comment: thanks for reminding about `AllowOverride All`, I absolutely forgot about it, and my super-cheap-hosting of course takes care about not-giving-me-any-free-will :D

Comment: index.php is already happening.  He wants to change it to index.html. Read the question.

Comment: do not forget to refresh the browser by e.g. `Ctrl+F5` to really check if changes applied, for me, it's almost a habit, still, even if correct changes are applied it might show cached content.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.php index.php3
```

Precedence is from left to right, so if you happen to have both html will be preferred

Comment: I didn't have the .htaccess problem.  My problem was that it was loading index.html beofe index.php.  So, this solution was the hint that solved my problem (not the original posted problem).

Answer (score 0):

Silly question, but have you proven that your htaccess file is being utilized?

See: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#allowoverride

Answer (score 0):

You have to check if there is any htaccess rule on parent directory that conflics with this rule, my problem was that, having a **RewriteEngine** on root directory and "/folder/" DirectoryIndex won't work.

Answer (score -4):

open your .htaccess file and add

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

Comment: index.php is already happening. He wants to change it to index.html. Read the question.